# ThreeJS DragControls in Angular5

Tags: angular, three.js

I am trying to setup threejs in angular5 (angular-cli) project.
The plain threejs works great by simply installing

```
 npm install three and npm install @types/three;
```

But i can't figure out a way to use controls which exists in three/examples/js/controls/DragControls.js

I tried following

- npm install three-dragcontrols.  This doesn't import DragControls and the object is always undefined

  'import {DragControls} from 'three-dragcontrols';
- tried adding all the js files in three/examples/js/controls in .angular-cli scripts tag.  But scripts js bundle is included before vendor bundle which includes ThreeJS.
- tried copying the controls to assets folder include as script tags in html page, but the window object THREE is undefined and hence it doesn't work.
- the only option i can see now is to checkin the code as source code and convert it to typescript (rename the file and fix linting issues etc)

What is the right way to include DragControls/MapControls etc in Angular application?

Comment: If that answer works for you, click on the check mark next to the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

In Node you can easily convert most libraries into modules, you are not confined to NPM repo. Get to the DragControls file and add the following line on top of everything else:

```
module.exports = function(){

   <library-code>...</library-code>

};
module.exports();
```

Note: **library-code** is just to get your attention, you just have to put the JavaScript code of that library in between **function(){};** brackets, assigned by module.exports and call it at the end of the code, like in the example above.

For instance, there wasn't an NPM module for CanvasJS I could actually use. So I turned it into a module. Don't forget the package.json you'll need, otherwise to Node, there are no modules.

From there, you'll be able to require() it. If you want to use it anywhere, create an Angular service and require() it in that file.

See this yourself at the following: https://github.com/Nchaka/-Kinaxis/blob/konkret/node_modules/canvasjs/canvasjs.min.js

If it helps you to learn by comparison, the non-Node version of that same application can be found at the following using the non-module CanvasJS version: https://github.com/Nchaka/Kinaxis